# I modified the code, I have suppliers as sheet names, but it seems to not run my code through all the sheets

Tags: vba, excel

**Original Code:**

```
Sub LoopThroughSheets()

Dim Months As Variant
Dim Month As Variant

Months = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", _
         "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

For Each Month In Months
    'Code goes here.
Next Month

End Sub
```

**Modified Code:**

```
Sub LoopThroughSheets()

Dim Suppliers As Variant
Dim Supplier As Variant

Suppliers = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", _
         "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q")

For Each Supplier In Suppliers
    'Code goes here.
Next Supplier

End Sub
```

Comment: Scott, thank you, it is my first time here, I did not know how to edit this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a template to use if your tabs are "lettered"

```
Sub LoopThroughSheets()
    Dim Suppliers As Variant, Supplier As Variant
    Suppliers = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q")
    For Each Supplier In Suppliers
        With Sheets(Supplier)
            .Range("A1").Value = "qwerty"
        End With
    Next Supplier
End Sub
```

Comment: I can try this, but my suppliers have specific names instead of letters, that was just an example, that they are not months. For example: you can say, my supplier names are Colgate, pepsodent, toyota, mahindra, etc. I have 18 different names.

Comment: I just added the "With" and "End With" to my code, it ran through one cycle and when I debug it, hovering over Sheets(Supplier), shows me the name of my second supplier, but still for some reason the code does not want to run.

Comment: **You must make absolutely certain that the set of names in the Array matches the Tab names.**  There should be no extra spaces and the upper/lower case must exactly match.

Comment: That is a great point, I checked and found some discrepancies. But, even now when I run the code, it only runs macro on activesheet but this time it does not stop by itself it just takes a little delay, but functions only once. When I do run it break points in, and re-run it again and again, the supplier seems to be taking up the next names from arrays, but still updates are not happening unless I am on that particular sheet and then running the macro.

Comment: I understand............please notice in my *template* code there is a **dot** at the beginning of the **Range** statement...........you need these **dot**s  in front of any **Range()** or **Cells()** code you have...........it is the **dot**s that make the loop work!!

Comment: But I thought that code is only functional if my names are alphabets, but they are not. Should I still include that in my code? If it is to be included, where is my code supposed to go?

Comment: YES........the **With** statement causes something like **.Range("A1")** to be interpreted as **Sheets("toyota").Range("A1")**

Comment: Okay, so I ran the code as suggested by you, every worksheet is getting "qwerty" in A1, but still the macro is only processed on the activesheet. I am sorry if I might be doing something fundamentally wrong, but this is the scenario. My code is okay, I know that, since it runs successfully on one sheet, I just dont understand why it won't loop.

Comment: I must leave the office soon.............I am sure you are nearly 95% there.......If you post more of your *actual code*, we can complete this later.

Comment: I should not post it here as it is public, I can put my code in generic terms, I cannot disclose some specific names. But thank you so much for your help so far. I can post the generic code here.

Comment: Excellent............post a simple generic extract that fails for you and we will fix that!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub RefreshFormulas2()
'
' RefreshFormulas2 Macro
'
' Sub LoopThroughSheets()

Dim Suppliers As Variant
Dim Supplier As Variant
Dim rng As Range
Dim UnusedColumn As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Suppliers = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q")

For Each Supplier In Suppliers
  With Sheets(Supplier)
    .Range("A1").Value = ""
    'PURPOSE: Selects only cells with values or formulas and excludes blank values (ie ="" or +"")
    Range("AG4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Set rng = Range("C4:C100")
    'Find a column with nothing in it
    Set UnusedColumn = Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1)
   'Create temporary calculation column to determine which cells to select (marked by an X)
    Intersect(rng.EntireRow, UnusedColumn) = Evaluate("IF(" & rng.Address & "="""","""",""X"")")

    'Make Selection
    Intersect(UnusedColumn.SpecialCells(xlConstants).EntireRow, rng.EntireColumn).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    'Remove Temporary Blank Caluclations
    UnusedColumn.Clear
    Range("AI4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Set rng = Range("E4:E100")

    'Find a column with nothing in it
    Set UnusedColumn = Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1)

    'Create temporary calculation column to determine which cells to select (marked by an X)
    Intersect(rng.EntireRow, UnusedColumn) = Evaluate("IF(" & rng.Address & "="""","""",""X"")")

    'Make Selection
    Intersect(UnusedColumn.SpecialCells(xlConstants).EntireRow, rng.EntireColumn).Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
              SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    'Remove Temporary Blank Caluclations
    UnusedColumn.Clear

    Range("AJ4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy

    Set rng = Range("F4:F100")

    'Find a column with nothing in it
    Set UnusedColumn = Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1)

    'Create temporary calculation column to determine which cells to select (marked by an X)
    Intersect(rng.EntireRow, UnusedColumn) = Evaluate("IF(" & rng.Address & "="""","""",""X"")")

    'Make Selection
    Intersect(UnusedColumn.SpecialCells(xlConstants).EntireRow, rng.EntireColumn).Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
              SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    'Remove Temporary Blank Caluclations
    UnusedColumn.Clear

    Range("AK4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy

    Set rng = Range("G4:G100")

    'Find a column with nothing in it
    Set UnusedColumn = Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1)

    'Create temporary calculation column to determine which cells to select (marked by an X)
    Intersect(rng.EntireRow, UnusedColumn) = Evaluate("IF(" & rng.Address & "="""","""",""X"")")

    'Make Selection
    Intersect(UnusedColumn.SpecialCells(xlConstants).EntireRow, rng.EntireColumn).Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    'Remove Temporary Blank Caluclations
    UnusedColumn.Clear

    Range("AL4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy

    Set rng = Range("H4:H100")

    'Find a column with nothing in it
    Set UnusedColumn = Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1)

    'Create temporary calculation column to determine which cells to select (marked by an X)
    Intersect(rng.EntireRow, UnusedColumn) = Evaluate("IF(" & rng.Address & "="""","""",""X"")")

    'Make Selection
    Intersect(UnusedColumn.SpecialCells(xlConstants).EntireRow, rng.EntireColumn).Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    'Remove Temporary Blank Caluclations
    UnusedColumn.Clear

    Range("AN4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Set rng = Range("J4:J100")

    'Find a column with nothing in it
    Set UnusedColumn = Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1)

    'Create temporary calculation column to determine which cells to select (marked by an X)
    Intersect(rng.EntireRow, UnusedColumn) = Evaluate("IF(" & rng.Address & "="""","""",""X"")")

    'Make Selection
    Intersect(UnusedColumn.SpecialCells(xlConstants).EntireRow, rng.EntireColumn).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    'Remove Temporary Blank Caluclations
    UnusedColumn.Clear
    ActiveSheet.Range("I4:I95").ClearContents

    ActiveSheet.Range("K5").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
  End With

Next Supplier

End Sub
```

Comment: Okay so my answer again came in a very bad format, I am not sure what is the issue but that I can figure out later. My code is very repetitive here, but seems to work. The only issue as I have mentioned is, the whole code after running once, does not run again for next sheet.

Comment: The simplest fix is to add an `.Activate` on the line after the `With`. That will ensure that the `Range` uses target the right sheet. Range always targets the most general thing it can, so `Range` on it's own targets the active sheet, `Sheets(1).Range` targets the first worksheet and `Sheets(1).Columns(1).Range`... you get the idea. This is true of a LOT of VBA functions, which is why you see such heavy use of with (which basically says "any time you see a dot as though we're half way through something, prepend with this object)

Comment: @tobriand: that thing worked like a magic. Also, I appreciate you explaining me the reasoning behind it, that would definitely help me in my future endeavors with vba. Thank you so much!